# A continues series of characters in a string how do I split it at a certain point e.g 30 charaacters in php

Tags: php, string, character

I'm trying to break/split a continues series of characters in a php string at a specific point
e.g.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

to

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: What is the "specific point"? After n characters?

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function called [`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/chunk_split) which does exactly what you ask...

```
$myLongString = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';

$splitString = chunk_split($myLongString, 20);

echo $splitString;

/*

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) with the $break parameter as " ".

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at `substr` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)..

eg:

```
substr('foobar', 0, 3). ' ';
```

yields

```
'foo '
```