# PHP or HTML/CSS solution for forcing line breaks in table

Tags: php, html, css, line-breaks

I have a table filled with user generated text.
The text spans for as much as the TD allows, however if the input is a string made of a long string with no breaking chars (white space, dash etc) it messes up the table.

e.g. ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg

How can I make it so that those strings wrap as well?

Thank you.

Comment: exactly duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348892/a-continues-series-of-characters-in-a-string-how-do-i-split-it-at-a-certain-point

Comment: Why duplication, here a CSS/HTML-way is asked too.

Comment: Yup, I don't want to truncate the string at all, I want to have it force-break when the container edge is reached when a string has no line breaking characters in it.

Comment: Agreed - this is different from the other thread; that was asking for PHP string manipulation, this is for HTML/CSS. The solution _may be_ PHP string manipulation, but the OP isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

table td, table th {
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+, Chrome, Firefox 3+ */
    overflow-wrap: break-word;   /* CSS3 standard: Chrome & Opera 2013+ */
}

/* Use this if you also want to preserve multiple spaces in text */
table td, table th {
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* CSS3 */
}
```

Here is an example:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/QPP8A/  (now out of date, sorry)

If you find this to hard to apply, you can use [PHP's wordwrap function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php):

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
```

Comment: Hmm, that's a nice touch. Problem is it only seems to work on elements with a set width and I have one that stretches automatically to fit a div with a preset width.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't. Neither does max-width. Stupid tables. :) Thanks a lot though, I set a fixed width and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, put a `<div>` with fixed width and it will work inside the `<td>`.

Comment: you have to set the style `table-layout` of the parent table to the value `fixed` to make it work with `<td>`

Comment: I know about the word wrap funtion in PHP, but it's not about limiting output but rather formatting it well. The long "ggggg..." messes up the layout.

Comment: I modified the comment for `word-wrap`: previous comment seemed to imply that this was needed only for IE. But it is also needed for other browsers (tried with FF 6, Chrome, Opera).

Answer (score 3):

try this jquery solution it will break the text after number of letters defined:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Word-Break

You can use it like this.

```
$('yourtable td').wordwrap({
        width: 50,
        cut:true,
        brk: '<br/>\n'
        })
```

Thanks

Comment: @Francisc i wrote this. I face the same scenario in one of my project.